# browsers seem to be ignoring display:inline-block and rendering as block

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress theme. I am developing on a local wamp environment with wordpress 4.1 installed and I am using the underscores_ base theme

I am trying to have the site-title in the left corner and the navigation menu on the right hand side at the top of my page. When I float the .site-title left and the .main-navigation right and set the display of both to inline-block the browser still seems to render them as blocks.

I have checked in the developer tools (Chrome) and under the "Computed" tab it appears to be rendering as block. When I expand this it says it is rendering as inline-block, though it doesn't act like it.

Here is an image of what I mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6TiG.jpg

Any help would be appreciated. I have never come across this before.

**RESOLVED**

I didn't notice that in the reset.css there was a rule that heading elements would clear:both. I added a rule to the relevant classes that set clear:none.

This ensured the floated elements lined up without trying to clear eachother.

Comment: Floated items are `display:block` as a "Computed Value" see [**MDN Reference on Float**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: Thank you, but in my css I these elements have the their dislpay set to inline-block. Why would this be ignored?

Comment: It's not being ignored..it's the "Computed Value" that's shown...that's all. Unless it's actually causing a problem it's not something to worry about.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you. There is a problem though. the elements are acting like block elements in that they aren't lining up next to each other like I would expect. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Then I suggest you demo the issue...but you probably don't need the inline block declaration anyway.

Comment: Schoolboy error, in the reset.css h1 was set to clear both, hence why they weren't lining up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3606924 you should add that as an answer and accept it so that this question appears closed.

Comment: @Paulie_D - This was exactly my problem - `float: left` was causing my `inline-block` elements to be `block` elements. Thanks! :)